# Django Rest Framework - Serializer doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a blog API that would consist of user posts and comment instances. I am using Django & Django Rest Framework to build the API that would return data in JSON format. Below is an example of the JSON data being returned:

```
    "id": 2,
    "user": 1,
    "user_photo": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/users/abc.jpg",
    "is_owner": true,
    "description": "Hey there, this is my post and I like it",
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "post": 2,
            "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/posts/foo.jpg",
            "comment": "This is image #1"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "post": 2,
            "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/posts/bar.jpg",
            "comment": "This is image #2"
        }
    ],
    "created": "2022-03-23T16:58:44.800255+03:00",
    "likes": [
        1
    ],
    "comment_count": 1,
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "post": 2,
            "text": "This is a comment on my post",
            "user": 1,
            "likes": [],
            "created": "2022-03-23T17:00:27.074362+03:00",
            "images": [
                3, <----- should be URL to the image, not just id (like above)
                4  <----- should be URL to the image, not just id (like above)
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My problem is that while the `Post` images are returned in the JSON correctly, my `PostComment` images are returned just as an array of id, without the URLs. I indicated with arrows in the code where I'm trying to get an array of objects (id & URLs).
I suspect this would be happening due to some issues in the serializer, but I just can't pinpoint it. Here is my serializer code:

```
class PostCommentImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostCommentImage
        comment = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='comment.id')
        fields = ('id', 'comment', 'image')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'comment',)

class PostCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostComment
        post = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='post.id')
        comment_images = PostCommentImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
        fields = ('id', 'post', 'text', 'likes', 'created', 'comment_images')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'created', 'comment_images', 'likes')

class PostImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostImage
        post = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='post.id')
        fields = ('id', 'post', 'image', 'comment')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'post')

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user_photo  = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    is_owner    = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    images = PostImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    comments = PostCommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    comment_count = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        post = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='post.id')
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'user_photo', 'is_owner', 'description', 'images', 'created', 'likes', 'comment_count', 'comments',)
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'user', 'user_photo', 'is_owner', 'images', 'created', 'comments', 'comment_count',)

    def get_user_photo(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        user = request.user
        return request.build_absolute_uri(obj.user.photo.url)

    def get_is_owner(self, obj):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if user == obj.user:
            return True
        else:
            return user.is_superuser
```

As you can see in my `PostCommentSerializer` I added the line`comment_images = PostCommentImageSerializer()`, so it should be returning an array of objects, not just an array of `id` integers, and the `related_name` in `models.py` is set correctly to 'comment_images', so I am at a loss of what could be the source of the problem.

I suspect it must be something simple, but I can't find the reason behind it.
Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: could you tell where comments' body is created (I mean the key in your response)? does it have another serializer? because it is not included in any of your serializers' fields or read_only_fields.

Comment: @Roham What do you mean? The are no other serializers for the PostComment and the save method is in the model class:
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
 super(PostComment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You have defined below serializer field in Meta class of PostCommentSerializer.

comment_images = PostCommentImageSerializer(
            many=True, read_only=True)

Correct Implementation is :

class PostCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comment_images = PostCommentImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
class Meta:
    model = PostComment
    post = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='post.id')
    fields = ('id', 'post', 'text', 'likes', 'created', 'comment_images')
    read_only_fields = ('id', 'created', 'comment_images', 'likes')
```